# Kotlin DSL Unresolved reference on settings.gradle.ktl

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am getting an unresolved reference build error on settings.gradle.kts when I am referencing variables from the buildSrc module.

The strange thing is that when I am using the variables from buildSrc, for example to the app level build.gradle.kts, everything works fine.

Also the error occurs only when I build/sync and I am not getting that error(red highlights) on the text editor and the navigation to that variable works fine.

Attached you find an image with the setup, thanks a lot.

[image: error messages]

Edit: Changing gradle version from 6.5 to 5.6.4 seems to fixed the problem, but I do not like that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing definitions from `buildSrc` in settings scripts was deprecated in Gradle 5.6.

From the docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#classes_from_buildsrc_are_no_longer_visible_to_settings_scripts

> Previously, the buildSrc project was built before applying the
> project’s settings script and its classes were visible within the
> script. Now, buildSrc is built after the settings script and its
> classes are not visible to it. The buildSrc classes remain visible to
> project build scripts and script plugins.

You would have to hardcode those string values defined in your `buildSrc` and write them in your `settings.gradle.kts`.

Comment: I see, but that created duplicates. Any work-arounds on that?

Comment: Here's a discussion on that issue which might help you: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11090