# Android Gradle 6.1.1 issue - ScriptCompilationException in settings.gradle.kts

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Gradle setup for my Android project and in
buildSrc -> Dependencies.kt

```
   object Modules {
      const val app = ":app"
      const val fedmei = ":fedmei"     
   }
```

and in my settings.gradle.kts

```
include(Modules.app, Modules.fedmei)
project(Modules.fedmei).projectDir = file("../../fedmei/android")
```

After I updated my gradle to 6.1.1 and the Android Gradle Plugin to 4.0.1, the above setup stopped working.

The only way I am able to make it work now is if I do this in my settings.gradle.kts

```
include(":app", ":fedmei")
project(":fedmei").projectDir = file("../../fedmei/android")
```

But this will make me lose the setup to declare my module names once and refer to them

The error is unable to resolve Module
Here is a little more detail

```
2020-08-22 20:11:48,495 [211666470]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run phased build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Settings file '/Users/FiveToNiner/projects/jimax/settings.gradle.kts' line: 1
Script compilation errors:

  Line 1: include(Modules.app, Modules.fedmei)
                  ^ Unresolved reference: Modules


Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public abstract fun project(p0: File!): ProjectDescriptor! defined in org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings
public abstract fun project(p0: String!): ProjectDescriptor! defined in org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings
```

Or the full exception:

```
* Exception is:
ScriptCompilationException(errors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: Modules, location=/private/var/folders/gy/v31sh8jj71x4h8nfgw9vyzz00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8854382277266306427.tmp/settings.gradle.kts (1:9)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: Modules, location=/private/var/folders/gy/v31sh8jj71x4h8nfgw9vyzz00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8854382277266306427.tmp/settings.gradle.kts (1:22)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: Modules, location=/private/var/folders/gy/v31sh8jj71x4h8nfgw9vyzz00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8854382277266306427.tmp/settings.gradle.kts (1:47)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: Modules, location=/private/var/folders/gy/v31sh8jj71x4h8nfgw9vyzz00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8854382277266306427.tmp/settings.gradle.kts (1:61)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: Modules, location=/private/var/folders/gy/v31sh8jj71x4h8nfgw9vyzz00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8854382277266306427.tmp/settings.gradle.kts (1:86)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public abstract fun project(p0: File!): ProjectDescriptor! defined in org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings
public abstract fun project(p0: String!): ProjectDescriptor! defined in org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings, location=/private/var/folders/gy/v31sh8jj71x4h8nfgw9vyzz00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8854382277266306427.tmp/settings.gradle.kts (2:1)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: Modules, location=/private/var/folders/gy/v31sh8jj71x4h8nfgw9vyzz00000gn/T/gradle-kotlin-dsl-8854382277266306427.tmp/settings.gradle.kts (2:9))])
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptModuleTo(KotlinCompiler.kt:177)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptToDirectory(KotlinCompiler.kt:136)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$compileScript$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:648)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$compileScript$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost$runCompileBuildOperation$1.call(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:166)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost$runCompileBuildOperation$1.call(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:163)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.runCompileBuildOperation(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:163)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$emitSpecializedProgramFor$cachedDir$1$1$1$1.invoke(Interpreter.kt:291)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$emitSpecializedProgramFor$cachedDir$1$1$1$1.invoke(Interpreter.kt:66)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.compileScript(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:647)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.compileStage1(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:630)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.compileStage1$default(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:626)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.emitEval(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:210)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.emit(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:185)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.emit(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:177)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.access$emit(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$emitStaticProgram$1$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:106)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$emitStaticProgram$1$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$overrideExecute$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:488)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$overrideExecute$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.bytecode.AsmExtensionsKt.method(AsmExtensions.kt:126)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.bytecode.AsmExtensionsKt.publicMethod(AsmExtensions.kt:109)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.bytecode.AsmExtensionsKt.publicMethod$default(AsmExtensions.kt:106)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.overrideExecute(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:487)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.access$overrideExecute(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$emitStaticProgram$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:105)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$emitStaticProgram$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$program$3.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:609)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$program$3.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.bytecode.AsmExtensionsKt.publicClass-LgnzLRE(AsmExtensions.kt:37)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.program-7MEG69U(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:607)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.access$program-7MEG69U(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.emitStaticProgram(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:732)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler.compile(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:96)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$emitSpecializedProgramFor$cachedDir$1.invoke(Interpreter.kt:294)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter$emitSpecializedProgramFor$cachedDir$1.invoke(Interpreter.kt:66)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCache.initializeCacheDir(ScriptCache.kt:114)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCache.access$initializeCacheDir(ScriptCache.kt:37)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCache$cacheDirFor$1.execute(ScriptCache.kt:60)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCache$cacheDirFor$1.execute(ScriptCache.kt:37)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache$Initializer.initialize(DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache.java:100)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess$1.run(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:86)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.doWriteAction(DefaultFileLockManager.java:215)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.writeFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:205)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.open(FixedSharedModeCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:139)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:78)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:42)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:95)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:126)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.cache.ScriptCache.cacheDirFor(ScriptCache.kt:67)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.cacheDirFor(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:261)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator$InterpreterHost.cachedDirFor(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:250)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.emitSpecializedProgramFor(Interpreter.kt:256)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.kt:183)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.StandardKotlinScriptEvaluator.evaluate(KotlinScriptEvaluator.kt:120)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:51)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPluginFactory$create$1.invoke(KotlinScriptPluginFactory.kt:36)
        at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.KotlinScriptPlugin.apply(KotlinScriptPlugin.kt:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:67)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.process(SettingsEvaluatedCallbackFiringSettingsProcessor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.initialization.RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.process(RootBuildCacheControllerSettingsProcessor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor$2.call(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.process(BuildOperationSettingsProcessor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:120)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(DefaultSettingsLoader.java:58)
        at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsAttachingSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CommandLineIncludedBuildSettingsLoader.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(ChildBuildRegisteringSettingsLoader.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.composite.CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(CompositeBuildSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(DefaultSettingsPreparer.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.doLoadBuild(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:59)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer$LoadBuild.run(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:395)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:387)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(BuildOperatingFiringSettingsPreparer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareSettings(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:225)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:180)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:87)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:68)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
```

Comment: Try FIle ->  invalidate caches/restart android studio. If it does not work then you added wrong path of 'settings.gradle.kts'

Comment: That didn't work. The path and the setup is the same pre and post upgrade

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62998524/7746134